# How can I obtain API response data from within a function?

Tags: javascript, scope, http-get, node-rest-client

Javascript noob here. Apologies if there are a ton of duplicate questions out there because it seems like this must be a fundamental js function thing, but I honestly can't find an answer to this. I'm trying to wrap an API GET call in a function, and I'm running into behavior that I don't understand. The code in question:

I'm using the node-rest-client package to call the mapquest geocoding API. I'm interested in the lat/long data only. 
`var Client = require('node-rest-client').Client;`

If I make the GET call like this, I can access `parsed` as an object, which is what I want.

```
var address = 'New York'
var client = new Client();
var parsed;
client.get("http://www.mapquestapi.com/geocoding/v1/address?" +
                'key=' + mapquestKeys.consumer_key +
                '&location=' + address,
            function(data, response) {
              parsed = data.results[0].locations[0].latLng
              }
            );

// parsed == {lat, long}
```

But if I wrap this in a function:

```
function geocode(address){
  var client = new Client();
  var parsed;
  client.get("http://www.mapquestapi.com/geocoding/v1/address?" +
                  'key=' + mapquestKeys.consumer_key +
                  '&location=' + address,
              function(data, response) {
                parsed = data.results[0].locations[0].latLng
                }
              );
    return parsed
}

var address = 'New York'
parsed = geocode(address);

// parsed === undefined
```

`parsed` doesn't seem to be affected by the inner function; it's undefined. How can I return `parsed` as an object containing the data I want as in the first example? What the heck is going on here?

Comment: you need to wrap this into a promise, or return the result with callback.

Callback would be like this:
```
function call(arg, callback) {
 client.get("http:////" + arg, function (data, response) {
  callback(data.results[0].locations[0].latLng)
 })

call("yolo", function (parsed) {
 console.log(parsed)
})
}
```

promise is well described here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: Why oh why do so many people start using things like Ajax but refuse to read anything about before trying to use it? The "A" is for asynchronous.

Comment: missed var for parsed variable outside function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In:

```
function geocode(address){
  var client = new Client();
  var parsed;
  client.get("http://www.mapquestapi.com/geocoding/v1/address?" +
                  'key=' + mapquestKeys.consumer_key +
                  '&location=' + address,
              function(data, response) {
                parsed = data.results[0].locations[0].latLng
                }
              );
    return parsed
}

var address = 'New York'
parsed = geocode(address);

// parsed === undefined
```

You never defined `parsed` outside of the scope of your function. Also you're returning `parsed` inside of the function before it's had a chance to retrieve from the GET request. If you wanted to do it this way, you'd need to put `return(prased)` inside the callback function of `client.get`. A better way to do it is to wrap it inside a Promise like so:

```
function geocode(address){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var client = new Client();
        client.get("http://www.mapquestapi.com/geocoding/v1/address?" +
                'key=' + mapquestKeys.consumer_key +
                '&location=' + address,
                function(data, response) {
                if(data){
                    resolve(data.results[0].locations[0].latLng)
                }
                else{
                    reject(response)
                }
                  });
    })
  };


var address = 'New York';
var parsed;
geocode(address).then(function(latlong){
    parsed = latlong
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err)});
```

Here, parsed will only evaluate to `latlong` once the Promise has been resolved (the GET request has returned successful). It will also reject the Promise if data of the GET request is NULL and return an error.

If you wanted to then do something with `parsed` you could include that in the `.then()` statement.

Learning how to code in Javascript means learning how to write code *asynchronously*. Promises help you treat things which are by default **asynchronous** as **synchronous**.

Comment: Returning `parsed` before the GET request itself had resolved was what was really confusing me. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

You never defined parsed in scope (externally to the function):

```
function geocode(address){
  var client = new Client();
  var parsed;
  client.get("http://www.mapquestapi.com/geocoding/v1/address?" +
                  'key=' + mapquestKeys.consumer_key +
                  '&location=' + address,
              function(data, response) {
                parsed = data.results[0].locations[0].latLng
                }
              );
    return parsed
}

var address = 'New York'
var parsed = geocode(address);
```

Notice the `var parsed = geocode(address);`

Answer (score 0):

you need to wrap this into a promise, or return the result with callback. Callback would be like this:

```
function call(arg, callback) {
 client.get("http:////" + arg, function (data, response) { 
  callback(data.results[0].locations[0].latLng)
 });
}

call("yolo", function (parsed) { console.log(parsed) })
```

promise is well described here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: This has nothing to do with a promise... this is just using a callback function.

Comment: @jmkmay As I said, it is possible to use callback approach as described in answer, or just promise.